# I can't include image

Tags: java, image, swing

I am making the game, and i have error with implementing the image, and I don't know how to fix it. Code is very simple, but I am a beginner.

### Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot instantiate the type Image

at Rabbit.render(Rabbit.java:9)
at Rabbit.main(Rabbit.java:13)
```

### Code

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;


public class Rabbit {
    public void render(Graphics g){
        Image rabbit = new Image("/Rabbit.png"); // Error
        g.drawImage(rabbit, 100, 100, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you facing? Please post the stack trace. Might be Image is not found at the path specified!

Comment: Resolve compilation errors ***before*** trying to run code!

Answer (score 2):

`java.awt.Image` has no constructor that accepts a `String`. Use `ImageIO.read` to read the image and preferably on application startup

Comment: In addition, here is a small program for reading a image through ImageIO.read http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.imageio/how-to-read-an-image-from-a-file-inputstream-o-2.html